# Show that there are only trivial solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I show that the only solutions of the diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=1$ are the trivial ones: $(x,y)=(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)$ ?

That's what I thought:

$$x \equiv 0,1  \pmod 2 \Rightarrow x^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod 2$$
$$y \equiv 0,1 \pmod 2 \Rightarrow y^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod 2$$

$x^2+y^2 \equiv 0,1 \pmod 2 $

Since $0 \not\equiv 1 $, we want $x^2+y^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and this relation is satisfied, when $x \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \wedge y \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ and when $x \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \wedge y \equiv 0 \pmod 2$

Is it right so far? If so, how can I continue, in order to show that the only solutions are these one:  $(x,y)=(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)$ ?

Comment: Well, if $\;x,y\in\Bbb Z\implies x^2\,,\,y^2\ge 1^2=1\;$ , so the only possibilites are what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use mod. Note that 
$$x^2+y^2=1\Rightarrow 1-x^2=y^2\ge 0\Rightarrow -1\le x\le 1\Rightarrow x=0,\pm 1.$$

For $x=0$, we have $x^2+y^2=1\Rightarrow y^2=1\Rightarrow y=\pm 1.$

For $x=\pm 1$, we have $x^2+y^2=1\Rightarrow 1+y^2=1\Rightarrow y=0.$

Hence, there are only four cases as 
$$(x,y)=(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0).$$

Comment: I understand.. But, how could I prove it, using mod?

Comment: If you insist in modular arithmetic you could argue that if either of $\;x,y\;$ is even *and not zero* then $\;x^2\ge 4\;$ (and the same if it is $\;y\;$), so it must be that they both *cannot* be even and, in fact, if one of them is then it **must** be zero.

Comment: @evinda: As Timbuc comments, you can get the fact that one of $x,y$ has to be zero. You can also do as the following : You can use mod to get the fact that $x,y$ have different parity. After that, if $x$ is odd, then $x^2\ge 1$, so $x^2=1$ and $y$ has to be zero.

Comment: Also, how can I show that these solutions are the only one?

Comment: @evinda: If you mean you want to know how to show that there are *only four* cases, then see my answer. I added a bit.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If a number between $|x|$ and $|y|$ is greater than one, $x^2+y^2$ is greater than one, hence the solutions have to be found in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\cap\{(x,y):\max(|x|,|y|)\leq 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not a number-theoretic answer, but you could see that $x^2+y^2=1$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ is a circle $\gamma$ of radius one centered at the origin, so every point of coordinates $(x,y)$ on $\gamma$ has distance $1$ from the origin. If you restrict to $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ you see that those are the only solutions.

Comment: How being part of the unit circle helps to prove that the only points with integers (or whatever) coordinates are the ones that the OP wrote?

Comment: Well, the solutions are the points on the circle with integer coordinates. The only such points are the trivial solutions mentioned.

Comment: @Timbuc Embed into a $2\times 2$ square, and check all the lattice points one by one if you need to.

Comment: @marco, I know. The question is how remarking the fact the points belong to the unit circle help for the proof?

Comment: @Slade, yes I know.

Comment: @Timbuc in this setting you can prove by enumeration, as Slade pointed out. Sometimes a change of perspective gives an easier solution- in this case seeing the geometry of the thing makes it trivial.

Comment: @marcotrevi, I still can't see your point: for example, in $\;x^2+y^2=25\;$ we have several integer points with no zero coordinate, but your argument here applies just the same if we *only* remark the geometric view.

Comment: ok, but the OP asked another question. Finding all the pythagorean triplets is another kind of quest.